jacoco plugn version update from 0.8.8 to 0.8.10 results huge coverage drop android
I updated jacoco version from 0.8.8 to 0.8.10 and too many classes coverage is dropped. Build is failing because of this coverage drop.
I tried covering this huge drop for few classes but it requires lot of time to cover whole project.
